# How to store results of a function?

Tags: r, function, loops

I am trying to store the results of the function below, 
I could only print the results but cannot save it as csv format. how can i save these results into a csv file?
Thanks in advance!!!

```
 calEAD=function(loan, R, final, startdate, first_enddate,enddate){
  I=loan*R
  start=as.Date(startdate)
  firstend=as.Date(first_enddate)
  p=firstend-start
  period=as.numeric(p)/365
  EADabc=0
  b=enddate-2017
  for(i in (0:b)){
    EADabc=I/((1+R)**(i+period))+EADabc
    print(EADabc)}
}

calEAD1=calEAD(6690012.88,0.0588,6690012.88, '2016-12-31','2017-08-29',2022)
calEAD2=calEAD(385000.12,0.0588,385000.12, '2016-12-31','2017-09-11',2023)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to keep every intermediate result of EADabc inside the for loop. In that case you could concatenate them to a vector like this:

```
calEAD=function(loan, R, final, startdate, first_enddate,enddate){
    I=loan*R
    start=as.Date(startdate)
    firstend=as.Date(first_enddate)
    p=firstend-start
    period=as.numeric(p)/365
    EADabc=0
    b=enddate-2017

    # Define an empty vector
    result = c()
    for(i in (0:b)){
        EADabc=I/((1+R)**(i+period))+EADabc

        # Append the current result to the vector
        result = c(result,EADabc)
    }

    # Make the function return this vector
    result
}
```

Result:

```
calEAD1=calEAD(6690012.88,0.0588,6690012.88, '2016-12-31','2017-08-29',2022)
calEAD2=calEAD(385000.12,0.0588,385000.12, '2016-12-31','2017-09-11',2023)

> calEAD1
[1]  378809  736581 1074484 1393622 1695037 1979713
> calEAD2
[1]  21755.57  42302.95  61709.24  80037.81  97348.51 113697.87 129139.28
```

If you want to save them to a csv file, do:

```
write.csv(x = calEAD1, file = "test.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! One more question: how can i save all EAD1 EAD2...EAD5 results into one single csv file ?

Comment: Are they all the same length?  csv files usually store tabular data (columns and rows), where the number of rows are the same for every column. If they are the same length do: `allEAD = data.frame(calEAD1, calEAD2, ...etc)` and then write to csv with `write.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You can use write.csv or the write.table functions.

```
for(i in (0:b))
{
EADabc=I/((1+R)**(i+period))+EADabc
write.table(EADabc, file = "file_name.csv",sep = ",", col.names = T, append =T)

}
```

Or
write.csv(EADabc, file = "file_name.csv", row.names = FALSE)